# Custom Layer with kwargs in tfjs

Tags: tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I'm new to tensorflowjs and I'm struggling to implement some custom layers, if someone could point me in the right direction that would be really helpful!
For example, I have a layer in InceptionResnetV1 architecture where I'm multiplying the layer by a constant scale (this was originally an unsupported Lambda layer which I'm switching out for a custom layer), but the value of this scale changes per block. This works fine in Keras with an implementation such as below, and using load_model with ScaleLayer in the custom objects

```
class ScaleLayer(tensorflow.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super(ScaleLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
      return tensorflow.multiply(inputs, kwargs.get('scale'))

    def get_config(self):
        return {}
```

```
x = ScaleLayer()(x, scale = tensorflow.constant(scale))
```

I tried defining this in a similar way in javascript and then registered the class

```
class ScaleLayer extends tf.layers.Layer {

  constructor(config?: any) {
    super(config || {});
  }

  call(input: tf.Tensor, kwargs: Kwargs) {
    return tf.tidy(() => {
      this.invokeCallHook(input, kwargs);
      const a = input;
      const b = kwargs['scale'];
      return tf.mul(a, b);
    });
  }
  
  static get className() {
    return 'ScaleLayer';
  }
}
```

```
tf.serialization.registerClass(ScaleLayer);
```

However I'm finding that the kwargs are always empty. I tried another similar method where I passed scale as another dimension of the input, then did input[0] * input[1], which again worked fine for the keras model but not in javascript.
I feel like I'm missing something key on the way to defining this kind of custom layer with a changing value per block on the javascript end, so if someone would be able to point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show how you are using an instance of `ScaleLayer` layer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(config?: any) {
    super(config || {});
  }
```

The config are passed to the parent constructor. But as indicated by the question, the `ScaleLayer` layer also needs to keep some config properties

```
constructor(config?: any) {
    super(config || {});
    // this.propertyOfInterest = config.propertyOfInterest 
    // make sure that config is an object;
    this.scale = config.scale
  }
```

Then for the computation, the `ScaleLayer` property `propertyOfInterest` can be used

```
call(input: tf.Tensor) {
    return tf.tidy(() => {
      this.invokeCallHook(input, kwargs);
      const a = input;
      return tf.mul(a, this.scale);
    });
  }
```

Use the layer this way:

```
const model = tf.sequential();
...
model.add(new ScaleLayer({scale: 1}));
...
```